# erasing from a vector with a base class ptr

Tags: c++, vector, multiple-inheritance, erase

I have a class called Circle used in a physics simulation.

A circle is declared as follows:

```
class Circle : public IPhysics,
               public IRenderable
{
...
}
```

The circles are created, then stored in a vector using their IRenderable pointer like so:

```
Circle* pC = new Circle( 
        mass,
        vec2( vCircles[x]._x, vCircles[x]._y ),     // position
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),                           // velocity
        vec2(0.0f, -g_kGRAVITY),                    // acceleration
        _ClientCfg.rGridSquareSideLen * 0.1f,       // radius
        colour, colour                              // colour, motion colour
    );

    if( pC != nullptr )
        streamed_circles.push_back(dynamic_cast<IRenderable*>(pC));
```

After they've been rendered, they're deleted from the back buffer like so:

```
std::vector<IRenderable*> _pbkBuffer;
...
_pBkBuffer->erase( _pBkBuffer->begin(), _pBkBuffer->end() );
```

This delete is causing memory leaks.

In order to erase objects from the back buffer vector, will I first have to cast them back to their leaf class types (e.g. Circle type or other leaf class type?)

edit:
I'm thinking that I'd need something like this:

```
std::for_each(
    _pBkBuffer->begin() + _nStaticRenderables, _pBkBuffer->end(),
    []( IRenderable* p )
    {
        if( typeid(*p) == typeid(Circle) )
        {
            Circle* pC = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(p);
            delete pC;
        }
    }
);
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to cast them back to `Circle *` (assuming the destructor of `IRenderable` is `virtual`). But you do need to call `delete` on each pointer in the `vector` before calling `vector::erase`.

A much, much better option is to change `std::vector<IRenderable*> _pbkBuffer;` to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IRenderable>> _pbkBuffer;`. Now calling `erase` should not leak any memory.

---

Note:

```
streamed_circles.push_back(dynamic_cast<IRenderable*>(pC));
```

The `dynamic_cast` above is unnecessary; `pC` is implicitly convertible to `IRenderable *`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `delete` on your items before removing them from the vector, otherwise you are losing the reference to them but not deleting the memory, as the `vector` only manage memory of its internal representation (it will call the destructor of `IRenderable*` which does nothing).

```
std::vector<IRenderable*> _pbkBuffer;

for (size_t i = 0; i < _pbkBuffer.size(); i++) {
    delete _pbkBuffer[i];
}
_pbkBuffer.clear();
```

You need to ensure that the destructor of `IRenderable` is `virtual` otherwise the `delete` will not work.

And you don't need the `dynamic_cast<IRenderable*>(pC)` when adding the elements to the `vector`. You only need `dynamic_cast` to cast downward in the type system (from a class to an inheriting class), not upward (from a class to its base class).